# The Sock Drawer Problem (Confused with inequality)

Tags: probability

Here is a picture of the question and part of the solution.

My question is, why and how do you square the inequality and insert 1/2.

The first draw is r/(r+b) and the second is (r-1)/(r+b-1)

so the whole think is r/(r+b) X (r-1)/(r+b-1) = 1/2

The inequality is r/(r+b) > (r-1)/(r+b-1)    This makes sense, but the next step doesn't which is

(r/(r+b))^2 > 1/2 > ((r-1)/(r+b-1))^2

Please help

I know the answer is 4. where R = 3 and B = 1 so the first draw is 3/4 and second is 2/3 so when squared there is one bigger then 1/2 and one smaller than 1/2 but how am I to know that before seeing the solution?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: "Here is a picture of the question and part of the solution."  Please **proofread** and then edit your posting.  Did you supply the picture using $\color{red}{\text{invisible ink}} ~?$

Comment: Actually, rather than providing the missing picture, it would be better to write out the complete problem (and the solution up to the part you are asking about) in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First note that when $1<m<n$, we have that

$$\begin{align}
mn - n &< mn - m \\[1mm]
n(m-1) &< m(n-1) \\[1mm]
\frac{m-1}{n-1} &< \frac{m}{n}
\end{align}$$

which means that we know that

$$\frac{r-1}{r+b-1} < \frac r{r+b}$$

Next note that if $0<a<b$, we have that

$$a^2 < ab < b^2$$

so that

$$\left( \frac{r-1}{r+b-1} \right)^2 < \underbrace{\left( \frac{r-1}{r+b-1} \right) \left( \frac{r}{r+b} \right)}_{=\frac{1}{2}} < \left( \frac r{r+b} \right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Given the inequality
$$
\frac r{r+b}>\frac{r-1}{r+b-1},\tag{$\ast$}
$$
multiply both sides by $\frac r{r+b}$:
$$\frac r{r+b}\times\frac r{r+b}>\frac r{r+b}\times\frac{r-1}{r+b-1},$$ and notice the RHS equals $\frac12$ by hypothesis. This gives the left side of the desired inequality:
$$\left(\frac r{r+b}\right)^2>\frac12.$$
To get the other side of the desired inequality, multiply both sides of $(\ast)$ by $\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}$.